# Setting android:id for Linear layout component

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am using the drag and drop feature to add a Linear layout in my  activity.
when i check the activity_main.xml there is the component created but no "android:id"
I cannot manually add the id , because there is no id for this layout in R.java . how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add android:id="@+id/YOUR_ID" to your XML, your IDE (I'm assuming eclipse) will recompile R.java, and you should be able to use R.id.YOUR_ID in your activity.

Answer (score 1):

You needn't use R.id for setting id programmatically. You can use any positive number for id:

```
myNewLayout.setId(newLayoutIndex);
```

According to View documentation

> The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy.
>   The identifier should be a positive number.

Comment: Agreed, but if you define the view in xml (he mentions activity_main.xml) it is better to set it there.  It's also worth noting that setting id's programmatically has the potential of creating duplicate ids, so it really needs to thought through before doing so.

Comment: If you want to use only one view - agrred. But what if you need to create and working with many views programmatically?